# How to create a list of html text entries from data.frame columns in r (without loops)?

Tags: html, r, text, r-glue

Imagine I have this df

```
df<-data.frame("A"=c("I","You","She"),"B"=c("kicked","like","saw"),"C"=c("can","dogs","birds"))
```

and some kind of text block base I want to use for HTML like this (df column names are in the brackets):

```
"Hello World<br> <b>{A} {B} the {C}.</b>"
```

I want to get out a list or collection like this:

```
c("Hello World<br> <b>I Kicked the can.</b>",
   "Hello World<br> <b>You like the dogs.</b>",
   "Hello World<br> <b>She saw the birds.</b>")
```

I can imagine iterating over each row of the data.frame, and then using the glue function, but it seems like there should be a short or 1 line solution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` and `do.call`

```
out <- do.call(sprintf, c(list("Hello World<br> <b>%s %s the %s.</b>"), df))
out
# [1] "Hello World<br> <b>I kicked the can.</b>" 
# [2] "Hello World<br> <b>You like the dogs.</b>"
# [3] "Hello World<br> <b>She saw the birds.</b>"
```

---

Helpful reference: [Can you pass a vector to a vararg?: Vector to sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368802/can-you-pass-a-vector-to-a-vararg-vector-to-sprintf)

Comment: Is there a way to specify the column name in this? Otherwise it is perfect. I could make a new df, but I would rather not if I can help it.

Comment: @bartcubrich A way might be to reorder your `df`, e.g., try `do.call(sprintf, c(list("Hello World<br> <b>%s %s the %s.</b>"), df[, c("C", "B", "A")]))`